# update page with with new data selected from dropdownlist in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have dropdown list using select_tag and I have button near it.

I have following requirements:
1) on click of submit button it should go to books#show action
2) Then in show action I retrieve the selected book from dropdown list
3) The show method should show details of book that I would retrieve from database
  i.e,the same page should update with this book details.

However,I am unable to perform none of this.

 In my view:

```
<%=  form_tag books_path do |f|%>
<%= label_tag "select book" %>
<%= select_tag "selectbook", options_from_collection_for_select(@bid,"book_id","book_id"), :prompt => "Select book",:class => 'cmbbook' %>
<%=  submit_tag "view ...", :disable_with => "Please wait." ,:action => "show"%>
<%end%>
```

In my controller

```
if(params[:selectbook])
      @books =  Book.where("book_id = ?",params[:selectbook])
else
      @books = Book.all
end
@bid= Books.select("book_id").uniq;

respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @books }
      format.json { render json: @books }
end
```

The submit method calling action `create` instead of `show` and I also wish the page autoupdate with new book data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found what to do:

 I have to write a method in javascript that calls **getJson()** method to appropriate controller and action and again update view using javascript.Thus,using ajax javascript problem is solved.However,I wish I can do same with pure ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should specify controller and action for the form, like this

```
form_tag( {:controller => 'your_controller', :action => "show"} )
```

For autoupdating page you should [read rails doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ajax_on_rails.html)

Comment: Thanks,it goes to show action.But,when I set ':remote => true',it doesn't update page.please help me!

Comment: It doesn't update the page because it just sends the request to your controller and gets an answer, but it doesn't know what to do with it. For updating page content you can use 
":update => updating_dom_el_id" or
":success: => code"
they both described in the article

Comment: can't it rerender the page with new `@books` data